# Complex Numbers : Why stop at 2 dimensions?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, real-numbers, analytic-number-theory, number-systems

Why is it enough to have extended the numbers to include only one orthogonal imaginary axis? I am wondering in the context of roots of polynomials. I know that the orthogonality of imaginary axis w.r.t. real axis is not the only property of imaginary numbers but there is also the relation $i^2=-1$. But still I am not able to think why is the solution space of polynomials complete with expanding the uni-dimensional real axis to 2-dimensional Complex numbers?

Comment: You might take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)

Comment: And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra

Comment: The usual question that gets asked along these lines is "if $i$ is the square root of $-1$, then what is the square root of $i$"? The answer to this is, perhaps surprisingly, $\pm(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$. More generally, we could use either de Moivre's or Euler's theorem to show that for any integer $n$ and any complex number $z = a + bi$, there exists an $n$th root $\sqrt[n]{z}$, which one could think of as a much weaker version of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: There is no intermediate field extension between R and C. In the fundamental theorem of algebra, C is enough to give you all the algebraic solutions to all polynomials. Note that given reals, you had to extend out to the complex world to find solutions, you do not need to go beyond complex numbers - they are algebraically closed fields. Quaternions are used too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several other useful extensions of $\mathbb{R}$. You can google quaternions (real dimension 4) and octonions (real dimension 8). Each time the dimension increases, we loose some property of $\mathbb{R}$. For example multiplication of quaternions is not commutative, and for octonions it is not associative. But there is a theorem of Frobenius which say that in some natural sense these are all possible extensions of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Could you add examples of simple real world problems which could not be solved using two dimensional complex numbers and required us to explore the higher dimensional complex numbers?

Comment: The Wikipedia articles have some examples, Mostly too technical to reproduce here. There are many other examples, unfortunately even more  technical.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the answer. I got some directions to look.